# how to populate values of nested array in Auto Complete Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multidimensional-array, autocomplete, material-ui

I have an array of Objects which includes an nested array ,

```
 [
  {
    code:1234,
    componentData:[{
       title:'B123456',
       Dates:'02-07-2021'
      }]
   }
 ]
```

Now i want to populate these values as option in dropdown of auto complete component using Material UI and Reactjs. I went through the [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#combo-box) and every example has a simple array of objects, which is not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to figure out how to show both `title` and `Dates` in the dropdown options of autocomplete.
And then try to fire the onchange function and get both `title` and `Dates` values on Select by the user.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-8k9hu?file=/demo.js
Code Sandbox Link : [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-8k9hu?file=/demo.js)

Something like this :
[image: Output I am trying to achieve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to show the nested `componentData` options, given an array of objects which all contain `componentData`. If that's right, you can use a `flatMap` to convert your nested array data to a single array of options, like:

```js
  const data =  [
    {
      code: 1234,
      componentData: [
        {
          title:'B123456',
          Dates:'02-07-2021'
        },
        {
          title:'B789',
          Dates:'02-08-2021'
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      code: 2345,
      componentData: [
        {
          title:'B234567',
          Dates:'02-07-2021'
        },
      ]
    }
  ];
  
  // `options` will be an Array of length 3 (for the 3 nested options above)
  const options = data.flatMap(object => object.componentData);

  // Render autocomplete given the `options`, where you define whatever `onChange` handler you need
  // to access the `title` and `Dates`, and provide a `renderOption` prop to choose how to present
  // the data as an option in your UI
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      options={options}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        if (newValue) {
          console.log(newValue.title);
          console.log(newValue.Dates);
        }
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />}
      renderOption={(option) => <Typography>{option.title} - {option.Dates}</Typography>}
    />
  );
```